App is working fine but editor is showing error
I am new to react, although my app is working just fine but my app.jsx is showing an error. A redline appears beneath the react word and when I am hovering the mouse pointer over it, it is saying "react is define but never used" Can any one of you help me, i am attaching the screenshot below
I am very new to react, i don't understand why there is an redline beneath the react word although my app is working just fine. I don't understand why my editor is showing a redline beneath the word react, it is saying that react was defined but never used.

since you said the app is working fine I'll assume that this is just a setting issue. You can try removing the import and see if it still works; also add the content of eslint.config.js to this post would be good for context

You don't need to explicitly import React default import in newer TS configs which I suspect you have

To resolve this, you have two options:
Keep the import and ignore the warning:
You can keep your current import import React from 'react' and simply ignore the warning. Your app will continue to work fine.
Remove the import (recommended for newer React versions):
If you're using React 17 or later with a modern build setup, you can remove the React import entirely. The JSX transform in newer versions doesn't require you to import React for just using JSX.
Your App.jsx file would then look like this:


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



This warning is just a linter suggestion and doesn't affect your app's functionality. It's trying to help you keep your code clean by pointing out unused imports.

To resolve this, either use React in your code or remove the import statement if it's unnecessary.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
